# Assigning new values doesn't work inside multiple api calls

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I am calling multiple apis with `axios` and `Promise.all` and trying to assign some new values (changing image to blurhash code with [plaiceholder](https://plaiceholder.co/)) inside data returned from each api like this

```js
  let promises = [];

  const urls = [
    `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}`,
    `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`,
  ];

  urls.forEach(function (url) {
    promises.push(
      axios.get(url).then(
        (data) => {
          data.data.results.map(async (one) => {
            const { blurhash, img } = await getPlaiceholder(
              `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${one.poster_path}`
            );
    
            // assigning new values and return the object 
            return {
              ...img,
              ...one,
              blurhash,
            };  
          });
          return { success: true, data: data };
        },
        function () {
          return { success: false }; 
        }
      )
    );
  });
  const [trendingRes, popularRes] = await Promise.all(promises);

  console.log(trendingRes.data.data) // new values don't get assigned
```

I am guessing it's because I used `async await` inside `.then()` so this `return { success: true, data: data };` doesn't wait for the new data to get updated and return the old data. But I couldn't find a way to fix it.

Comment: my guess is `data.data.results.map` you're basically throwing away the result in this map - also, mixing .then and async/await makes for code that is not very readable

Comment: Yes, but I don't know where else should I assign new values inside each api call and make the code more readable. I am also following this [code](https://github.com/joe-bell/plaiceholder/blob/main/examples/next/src/pages/blurhash/multiple.tsx) from github

Comment: you're also not handling possible errors in `getPlaiceholder`

Comment: that code on github has a single .then ... `.then((values) => values)` .. clearly the author has no clue, since `.then((values) => values)` is redundant and does absolutely nothing useful

Comment: I would recommend splitting out some of that code into separate functions - it'll make it far easier to **read** - I think what you're trying to do is `Promise.all(urls.map((url) => axios.get(url).then((data) => Promises.all(data.data.results.map((one) => getPlaiceholder(\`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${one.poster_path}\`).then(({blurhash, img }) => ({...img, ...one, blurhash})))),() > ({success: false})))).then(([trendingRes, popularRes]) => { /* here you have thhe results you're after */ });` - you can see how unreadable that is, and it still doesn't handle rejections in `getPlaiceHolder`

Comment: Thanks, I modified your code and it fixed my issue. Could you post an answer with that code so I can accept that as an answer.

Comment: oh, does that code work!!! I'm that good!!

Comment: Yeah, I just copied your code, added error handling and some codes in final `.then()`